# Nginx and gunicron serve django app and media files on the same port

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a remote server used to serve a django application. when I choose `DEBUG=False` I had to add a nginx server to serve media files from /media folder.
when I try to restart nginx after running gunicron I get an error saying that port 8000 is used.
how do I manage to serve the app and the media files on the same port?
This is the actual content of mysite_nginx.conf file

```
server {
listen 8000;
listen [::]:80;

    ... 

location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8000";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx server block should listen to port 80 only. Nginx is working as reverse proxy here.

```
server { 
             listen 80; 
             listen [::]:80; 
             ...
             location / { 
                   proxy_pass "http://localhost:8000";
                   } 
         }
```